# navigation bar disappear when using filezilla on IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, filezilla

Having using filezilla,but have a problem occuring,hope that someone can help,the problem are as follow:

1. The website is able to work well in IE and Chorme when browsing in other areas away from the Hosting or ftp place

2.but when in office,the webpage start having problem not working well in IE 8, especially the navigation bar is half disappear

Can i know why? Can anyone help

Comment: can you please add tags to your question

Answer (score 0):

try updating it or redownloading it if that still doesn't work then u should have never used IE8 as not many people use IE or Firefox anymore

Comment: does it relate to Active Scripting matter?